# What does Eclipse's "build path" mean

Tags: eclipse, plugins, build, path, eclipse-plugin

I have been trying to use a GWT plugin for Eclipse, and the author says that I should

> "unzip the plugin archive and paste it
>   in the project's build path".

So my project is created at `C:\Users\Rishi\workspace\hellocharts`

Where exactly should I put it ?

I'm using Eclipse Helios Service Release 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the libraries in a folder inside your project, e.g. `C:\Users\Rishi\workspace\hellocharts\lib`

In the exclipse project properties you have a section called "Java Build Path". You can add libraries (jars) in there. You have to add the gwt libraries in there.

You can also select the libraries in the Project Explorer, than right click and choose "Build Path"->"Add to Build Path".

You have to add the libraries to the build path, so that eclipse knows about them. Otherwise you can not use them in the project.

If its not a jar but source files, you will have to put them in your src folder or add the folder as src folder in the "Java Build Path" section.

Answer (score 1):

Start a new project in the Java perspective. Select the project name, right-click on it, and Build Path -> Configure Build Path.

Add source code on the Projects tab or add jar files on the Libraries tab. The Problems tab at the bottom will tell you what other libraries you will need to add.

Comment: You are quite welcome! BTW, Sometimes you will get a red X or red ! on a project, but you cannot easily drill into the source files to find out what is wrong. The Problems tab will give you more information, such an implied .class file.